# Relationship between gamma and chi-squared distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

If $$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i^2$$ where $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, i.e. all $X_i$ are i.i.d. normal random variables of zero mean with same variances, then $$Y \sim \Gamma\left(\frac{N}{2},2\sigma^2\right).$$

I know the chi-squared distribution is a special case of the gamma distribution, but could not derive the chi-squared distribution for random variable $Y$. Any help, please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Some background

The $\chi^2_n$ distribution is defined as the distribution that results from summing the squares of $n$ independent random variables $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so:
$$\text{If }X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)\text{ and are independent, then }Y_1=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\sim \chi^2_n,$$
where $X\sim Y$ denotes that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution (EDIT: *$\chi_n^2$ will denote both a Chi squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom and a random variable with such distribution*). Now, the pdf of the $\chi^2_n$ distribution is
$$
f_{\chi^2}(x;n)=\frac{1}{2^\frac{n}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}},\quad \text{for } x\geq0\text{ (and $0$ otherwise).}
$$
So, indeed the $\chi^2_n$ distribution is a particular case of the $\Gamma(p,a)$ distribution with pdf
$$
f_\Gamma(x;a,p)=\frac{1}{a^p\Gamma(p)}x^{p-1}e^{-\frac{x}{a}},\quad \text{for } x\geq0\text{ (and $0$ otherwise).}
$$
Now it is clear that $\chi_n^2\sim\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2},2\right)$.

### Your case

The difference in your case is that you have normal variables $X_i$ with common variances $\sigma^2\neq1$. But a similar distribution arises in that case:
$$Y_2=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2=\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{X_i}{\sigma}\right)^2\sim\sigma^2\chi_n^2,$$
so $Y$ follows the distribution resulting from multiplying a $\chi_n^2$ random variable with $\sigma^2$. This is easily obtained with a transformation of random variables ($Y_2=\sigma^2Y_1$):
$$
f_{\sigma^2\chi^2}(x;n)=f_{\chi^2}\left(\frac{x}{\sigma^2};n\right)\frac{1}{\sigma^2}.
$$
Note that this is the same as saying that $Y_2\sim\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2},2\sigma^2\right)$ since $\sigma^2$ can be absorbed by the Gamma's $a$ parameter.

### Note

If you want to derive the pdf of the $\chi^2_n$ from scratch (which also applies to the situation with $\sigma^2\neq1$ under minor changes), you can follow the first step  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution) for the $\chi_1^2$ using standard transformation for random variables. Then, you may either follow the next steps or shorten the proof relying in the convolution properties of the Gamma distribution and its relationship with the $\chi^2_n$ described above.

Comment: Nice description (+1).
But I am doubtful when you say that $Y_2\sim\sigma^2\chi_n^2,$ probably it should be  $Y_2=\sigma^2U,$ where $U\sim\chi_n^2.$ And finally, $
f_{\sigma^2 U}(x;n)=f_{\chi^2}\left(\frac{x}{\sigma^2};n\right)\frac{1}{\sigma^2}.$

Comment: Thanks @kaka. On the first point, actually with the notation $\sigma^2\chi_n^2$ I am referring to the random variable that arises when you multiply a $\chi^2_n$ variable by $\sigma^2$, so both of us are saying the same... On the second point, recall that $f_{\chi^2}(x;n)$ is the notation I used to refer to the density of a $\chi^2_n$ (the parameter $n$ appears as a second argument). With your notation, the density of $\sigma^2\chi^2_n$ will read as $f_{\chi_n^2}(x;n)$, which is also OK, but you are repeating twice the $n$.

Comment: But in the very first equation you defined $\mathcal{X}_n^2$ as a distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2.$

Comment: Yes, and in the equation for $Y_2$ the $X_i$'s have variance $\sigma^2$, so $\frac{X_i}{\sigma}$ is like $X_i$ in the first equation.

Comment: I mean this equation $Y_1=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\sim \chi^2_n.$ ($\chi^2_n$ is a distribution-function and NOT a random variable)

Comment: $\chi_n^2$ denotes the Chi squared distribution function with $n$ degrees of freedom and also a random variable that follows such distribution. This is maybe an abuse of notation, but the meaning should be clear. I will edit the answer to clarify it nevertheless.

Comment: I have not checked this in detail, but just thinking about scaling, shouldn't the the distribution be $\Gamma(N/2,2σ)$, not $\Gamma(N/2,2σ^2)$?

Comment: Yes, in case $\sigma=1$ :)

Comment: @NatKuhn : The parameters of the $\Gamma (\alpha , \beta)$-distribution are known as the shape parameter ($\alpha$) and scale parameter ($\beta$) respectively. The distribution has the nice property that the sum of two independent random variables with the same scale parameter is again $\Gamma$ with shape equal to the sum of the shapes.
Moreover, a $\Gamma$-distributed random variable multiplied by a scalar is again $\Gamma$ with the scale parameter multiplied by the scalar.

Note in particular that the scale parameter is not the variance.

Comment: @KetilBT, thanks. I was confused because although the $X_i$ scale by $\sigma$, the $\chi^2$ scales by $\sigma^2$

Comment: @NatKuhn : No worries. I guess I could have said it more compactly by noting that if $X \sim \Gamma ( \alpha, \beta)$ then $a X \sim \Gamma(\alpha, a \beta)$ for $a > 0$ and $V(X) = \alpha \beta^2$ meaning that $\sigma^2 X \sim \Gamma ( \alpha, \sigma^2 \beta)$ with $V(X) = \alpha (\sigma^2 \beta)^2$. Not sure if that helps though?