# An unbiased estimator of σ³

Tags: variance, estimation, unbiased-estimator

As it was suggested in the linked answer, [$s_n = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n - 1}}$ is not an unbiased estimator of $\sigma$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3932/145631).

I suspect neither $s_n^3 = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n - 1}}^3$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^3$.

Then, what is the formula for the unbiased estimator?

Comment: It depends on the distribution in both cases (estimating $\sigma$ and $\sigma^3$). For estimating variance it doesn't (assuming the variance exists). You may find [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131341/for-which-distributions-is-there-a-closed-form-unbiased-estimator-for-the-standa) of some use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Let us consider a Normal sample.** Since$$\sigma^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$$which is [also a Gamma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/118676/7224) $\mathcal{Ga}(n-1,1/2)$ variate, the $3/2$ moment of this variate is
$$\int_0^\infty z^{3/2}z^{n-1-1}\exp\{-z/2\}2^{-(n-1)}\Gamma(n-1)^{-1}\text{d}z=\frac{2^{(n-1)+3/2}\Gamma(n-1+3/2)}{2^{n-1}\Gamma(n-1)}$$i.e.
$$\frac{2^{3/2}\Gamma(n-1+3/2)}{\Gamma(n-1)}$$This implies that
$$\frac{\Gamma(n-1)}{2^{3/2}\Gamma(n-1+3/2)}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x}_n)^2\right\}^{3/2}$$is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^3$ in the Normal case. Now, as discussed in [my earlier answer to an earlier question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/131371/7224), this estimator does not provide an unbiased estimator for other scale families of distributions and there is no such an estimator for all distributions, relating to a [1968 paper by Peter Bickel and Erich Lehmann](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177697370).

Comment: Maybe it is a silly question, but what does $\mathcal{Ga}(n - 1 / 1 / 2)$ mean?

Comment: @abukaj, this is a statistical/probability notation, means a gamma distribution with shape = n-1, and scale=1/2. This is a somewhat standard notation.