# Relationship between the gamma distribution and Non-central chi squared distribution?

Tags: gamma-distribution, non-central, chi-squared-distribution

If $Y = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 $, where $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, i.e. all $X_i$ are i.i.d gaussian random variables of same mean and variance, then what is the resultant PDF of $Y$? How the resultant PDF of $Y$ can be interms of Gamma distribution?

I know that, if the mean is zero, the result follows as given in [Relationship between gamma and chi-squared distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118676/relationship-between-gamma-and-chi-squared-distribution), but how it can be derived for the case if the mean is zero?

Comment: It's unclear what you're attempting to derive or what kind of relationship you're looking for.  Could you clarify?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function for how the non-central CDF can be expressed as an *infinite sum* of central CDFs.

Comment: @whuber I assume that you meant a _weighted_ sum of CDFs (with weights summing to $1$) because an infinite _unweighted_ sum of CDFs would diverge as the argument increased without bound.

Comment: @Dilip Of course, thank you: I should have written *linear combination* rather than "sum."

Answer (score 3):

You can put this into the form of a non-central chi-squared distribution by scaling the random variables to get unit variance.  Since $X_i / \sigma \sim \text{IID N}(\mu / \sigma, 1)$ you have:
$$\frac{Y}{\sigma} = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{X_i}{\sigma} \sim \text{Noncentral Chi-Sq} \Big( DF = N, \lambda = \frac{N \mu^2}{\sigma^2} \Big).
$$
There is no simple form for the PDF of the non-central chi-squared distribution.  It can be written as the product of a gamma density and a [confluent hypergeometric limiting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#The_series_0F1).  Using this form, and adjusting for the scaling transform you get the density expression:
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sigma} \cdot \exp(-\tfrac{\lambda}{2}) \cdot {}_0 F_1 (; \tfrac{N}{2} ; \tfrac{\lambda}{2} \cdot \tfrac{y}{2}) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{2^{-N/2}}{\Gamma(\tfrac{N}{2})} y^{N/2-1} \exp(-\tfrac{y}{2}) }_{\text{Gamma Density}} \quad \quad \text{for }y \geqslant 0
$$