# How to calculate mean and variance of non central chi distribution of the problem?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, non-central, chi-distribution

If $Y = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2} $, where $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, i.e. all $X_i$ are i.i.d gaussian random variables of same mean and variance, then what is the resultant PDF of $Y$? How to calculate the mean and variance of the resultant pdf?

Comment: This is only a slight variation of your other [answered question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353938/relationship-between-the-gamma-distribution-and-non-central-chi-squared-distribu/354044#354044) - since you already know you need to look at the [noncentral chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution), it is worth looking up this distribution first.  Does this clarify your question?

Comment: It should be possible to adapt the technique from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317095/expectation-of-square-root-of-sum-of-independent-squared-uniform-random-variable/317475#317475

Comment: @Ben No sir, no clarity

Comment: With the information @Ben gave you, you can now [look up the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution).  Is that what you seek, or do you want to know how the solution is derived?